# On TeamCity, Mercurial repo is checked out without execute bit set

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, executable, ubuntu-14.04, teamcity-9.0

In my Mercurial repository, I have some build scripts. However, when TeamCity checks out the repo, it doesn't set the execute bit on them, even though it's set in the repository. The build then fails, as it can't run the scripts, as you would expect. How do I make TeamCity respect the execute bit?

I am running TeamCity 9.0 on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the VCS checkout mode to Agent rather than Server fixed this problem for me.

To change the VCS checkout mode:

- On the project configuration settings, go to Version Control Settings
- Click on Show advanced options
- Change VCS checkout mode from Automatically on server to Automatically on agent